# Connection string for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, connection-string

I am trying to write my connection string in my appsettings.json file and bring it into my startup file through an extension class but I keep getting a

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString.

I have been using various examples but can't seem to see this new setup with ASP.NET Core 2.2 startup class.`And I'm using PostgreSql

appsetting.json file

```
 {
  "PostgreConnectionString": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=1;Password=1234;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Demo;Pooling=true;Integrated Security=true;",

"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
}
```

ServiceExtension.cs

```
public static void ConfigurePostgreSQL(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var connectionString = config["PostgreConnectionString:DefaultConnection"];
            services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(config.GetConnectionString(connectionString))); --Error in this line value cannot be null
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.ConfigurePostgreSQL(Configuration);
```

Comment: Can you get the connect string when debug the `ConfigurePostgreSQL` function ? It was not null in my testing .

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the nesting brackets ! Appsettings.json generate a ConnectionStrings object imbricated in "Logging" object. 
Put ConnectionStrings out and your Configuration.GetConnectionStrings will works !

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core I use:

```
_connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("PostgreConnectionString");
```

config

```
{     
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PostgreConnectionString": "string"
  }
}
```

it works